# JavaFx Event argument type mismatch

Tags: java, events, javafx

I using JavaFx for first time and  I encountered a problem with events. I built a form with SceneBuilder and I add an event on .fxml and controller but it's always return with:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

**FirstScene.fxml:**

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" styleClass="background" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="examlog.gui.FirstSceneController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@dark_style.css" />
    </stylesheets>
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="firstScene_tableView" layoutX="30.0" layoutY="42.0" prefHeight="287.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="71.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="42.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn text="C1" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="70.0" text="C2" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Létrehozott munkafolyamatok:" />
      <Button fx:id="firstScene_newbutton" layoutX="522.0" layoutY="353.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#newButtonClick" text="ÚJ" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**FirstSceneController.java:**

```
public class FirstSceneController implements Initializable {

    @FXML 
    private Button firstScene_newbutton;
    @FXML 
    private TableView firstScene_tableView;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }

@FXML 
    private void newButtonClick(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");

    }



}
```

**JavaFxApplication.java:**

```
public class JavaFXApplication extends Application {

    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.stage = primaryStage;
        try {
            FirstScene();
            primaryStage.setTitle("FXML is Simple");
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public void FirstScene() throws IOException {
        AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(JavaFXApplication.class.getResource("FirstScene.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(page);
        stage.setScene(scene);

    }

}
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1757)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3437)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$7900(Scene.java:3365)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3733)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/14271771.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `onAction="#newButtonClick"`, not `onMouseClicked`.

Comment: Thank you @James. This really saved my day and a lot of headache!

Comment: For me, IntelliJ says that "Attribute onAction is not allowed here".

Comment: Then how do you handle onMouseClicked event?

Answer (score 10):

Try using `KeyEvent` instead of `ActionEvent`

```
@FXML
private void newButtonClick(KeyEvent event) { ...}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a `mouseClicked` event, simply change your `newButtonClicked` method to take in `MouseEvent`

```
@FXML
private void newButtonClick(MouseEvent event){...}
```

Comment: Make sure to use a javafx.scene.input MouseEvent, not the default java.awt one.

Answer (score 0):

instead of onMouseClicked you should use onAction