# JavaFx DatePicker onHiding and onHidden arguement type mismatch

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, datepicker, scenebuilder

I' using SceneBuilder to create a Java FX project and I'm running into an arguement type mismatch when trying to handle onHiding and onHidden for fx date pickers (Exception message at the end).

I've already looked at the answer here: [JavaFx Event argument type mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079062/javafx-event-argument-type-mismatch).

The first solution won't work for me because I need to perform an action during and after the hiding process. I tried the second solution, and as per my suspicions, it also did not to work.

Here's the FXML controller:

```
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXCheckBox;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDatePicker;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXRadioButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;

public class EditActionWindowController {
    private Task task = null;

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField txtfName;

    @FXML
    private JFXRadioButton radUrgent;

    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup priorityGroup;

    @FXML
    private JFXRadioButton radCurrent;

    @FXML
    private JFXRadioButton radEventual;

    @FXML
    private JFXRadioButton radInactive;

    @FXML
    private JFXCheckBox chkbUrgent;

    @FXML
    private JFXCheckBox chkbCurrent;

    @FXML
    private JFXDatePicker currentDatePicker;

    @FXML
    private JFXDatePicker urgentDatePicker;

    @FXML
    private JFXCheckBox chkbEventual;

    @FXML
    private JFXDatePicker eventualDatePicker;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btnComment;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btnHistory;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btnPrint;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btnClose;

    @FXML
    void btnCommentAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void btnHistoryOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void btnPrintOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void chkbCurrentAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void chkbEventualAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void chkbUrgentAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void currentDatePickerOnHidden(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void currentDatePickerOnHiding(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void eventualDatePickerOnHidden(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void eventualDatePickerOnHiding(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void radCurrentAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void radEventualAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void radInactiveAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void radUrgentAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void urgentDatePickerOnHidden(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void urgentDatePickerOnHiding(ActionEvent event) {

    }
}
```

And here's the FXML generated by SceneBuilder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXCheckBox?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDatePicker?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXRadioButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>

<ScrollPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="460.0" prefWidth="795.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="frontend.EditActionWindowController">
  <content>
    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="449.0" prefWidth="781.0">
         <children>
            <JFXTextField fx:id="txtfName" focusColor="#315de4" labelFloat="true" layoutX="48.0" layoutY="32.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="372.0" promptText="Name" />
            <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#c6c8c9" height="29.0" layoutX="584.0" layoutY="89.0" opacity="0.32" stroke="#0004f8" strokeType="INSIDE" width="130.0" />
            <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#c6c8c9" height="29.0" layoutX="584.0" layoutY="131.0" opacity="0.32" stroke="#0004f8" strokeType="INSIDE" width="130.0" />
            <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#c6c8c9" height="29.0" layoutX="585.0" layoutY="168.0" opacity="0.32" stroke="#0004f8" strokeType="INSIDE" width="130.0" />
            <JFXRadioButton fx:id="radUrgent" layoutX="48.0" layoutY="103.0" onAction="#radUrgentAction" text="Urgent">
               <toggleGroup>
                  <ToggleGroup fx:id="priorityGroup" />
               </toggleGroup>
            </JFXRadioButton>
            <JFXRadioButton fx:id="radCurrent" layoutX="48.0" layoutY="128.0" onAction="#radCurrentAction" text="Current" toggleGroup="$priorityGroup" />
            <JFXRadioButton fx:id="radEventual" layoutX="48.0" layoutY="151.0" onAction="#radEventualAction" text="Eventual" toggleGroup="$priorityGroup" />
            <JFXRadioButton fx:id="radInactive" layoutX="48.0" layoutY="174.0" onAction="#radInactiveAction" text="Inactive" toggleGroup="$priorityGroup" />
            <JFXCheckBox fx:id="chkbUrgent" checkedColor="#10859c" layoutX="47.0" layoutY="271.0" onAction="#chkbUrgentAction" text="Elevates to Urgent on:" />
            <JFXCheckBox fx:id="chkbCurrent" checkedColor="#10859c" layoutX="48.0" layoutY="313.0" onAction="#chkbCurrentAction" text="Elevates to Current on:" />
            <JFXDatePicker fx:id="currentDatePicker" defaultColor="#08008f" editable="false" layoutX="209.0" layoutY="306.0" onHidden="#currentDatePickerOnHidden" onHiding="#currentDatePickerOnHiding" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="201.0" promptText="Task becomes Current on..." />
            <JFXDatePicker fx:id="urgentDatePicker" editable="false" layoutX="209.0" layoutY="266.0" onHidden="#urgentDatePickerOnHidden" onHiding="#urgentDatePickerOnHiding" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="200.0" promptText="Task becomes Urgent on..." />
            <JFXCheckBox fx:id="chkbEventual" layoutX="48.0" layoutY="353.0" onAction="#chkbEventualAction" text="Elevates to Eventual on:" />
            <JFXDatePicker fx:id="eventualDatePicker" editable="false" layoutX="216.0" layoutY="348.0" onHidden="#eventualDatePickerOnHidden" onHiding="#eventualDatePickerOnHiding" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="196.0" promptText="Task becomes Eventual on..." />
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnComment" buttonType="RAISED" layoutX="584.0" layoutY="88.0" onAction="#btnCommentAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="130.0" ripplerFill="#0040ff" text="Comment" />
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnHistory" buttonType="RAISED" layoutX="584.0" layoutY="131.0" onAction="#btnHistoryOnAction" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="129.0" text="History" />
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnPrint" buttonType="RAISED" layoutX="586.0" layoutY="168.0" onAction="#btnPrintOnAction" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="129.0" text="Print" />
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnClose" cancelButton="true" layoutX="641.0" layoutY="368.0" text="Close" visible="false" />
         </children></AnchorPane>
  </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

And Here's the exception message:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.setShowing(ComboBoxBase.java:183)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.hide(ComboBoxBase.java:400)
    at com.jfoenix.skins.JFXDatePickerSkin.syncWithAutoUpdate(JFXDatePickerSkin.java:241)
    at com.jfoenix.controls.behavior.JFXDatePickerBehavior.onAutoHide(JFXDatePickerBehavior.java:66)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl.lambda$createPopup$294(ComboBoxPopupControl.java:253)
    at javafx.stage.PopupWindow.doAutoHide(PopupWindow.java:840)
    at javafx.stage.PopupWindow$PopupEventRedirector.handleAutoHidingEvents(PopupWindow.java:1025)
    at javafx.stage.PopupWindow$PopupEventRedirector.handleRedirectedEvent(PopupWindow.java:967)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventRedirector.dispatchCapturingEvent(EventRedirector.java:106)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchCapturingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:43)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:52)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventRedirector.redirectEvent(EventRedirector.java:124)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventRedirector.dispatchCapturingEvent(EventRedirector.java:103)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchCapturingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:43)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:52)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(WinApplication.java:218)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:511)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:107)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:583)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:474)
    at frontend.EditActionWindow.<init>(EditActionWindow.java:34)
    at MainController$2.handle(MainController.java:277)
    at MainController$2.handle(MainController.java:1)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.setShowing(ComboBoxBase.java:183)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.hide(ComboBoxBase.java:400)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxBaseSkin.focusLost(ComboBoxBaseSkin.java:99)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxBaseSkin.lambda$new$290(ComboBoxBaseSkin.java:87)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.scene.Node$FocusedProperty.notifyListeners(Node.java:7720)
    at javafx.scene.Node.setFocused(Node.java:7773)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.setWindowFocused(Scene.java:3932)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.lambda$new$11(Scene.java:3954)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setFocused(Window.java:439)
    at com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowPeerListener.changedFocused(WindowPeerListener.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:100)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:40)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.lambda$handleWindowEvent$423(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:150)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.handleWindowEvent(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.handleWindowEvent(Window.java:1266)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.notifyFocus(Window.java:1245)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinWindow._requestFocus(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.requestFocus(Window.java:727)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.requestFocus(Window.java:732)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.requestToFront(WindowStage.java:875)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.setPlatformEnabled(WindowStage.java:844)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.setEnabled(WindowStage.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.setVisible(WindowStage.java:485)
    at javafx.stage.Window$9.invalidated(Window.java:872)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:109)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:922)
    at javafx.stage.Window.hide(Window.java:947)
    at com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowCloseRequestHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(WindowCloseRequestHandler.java:45)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at com.sun.javafx.stage.WindowPeerListener.closing(WindowPeerListener.java:88)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:121)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.run(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:40)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.lambda$handleWindowEvent$423(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:150)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassWindowEventHandler.handleWindowEvent(GlassWindowEventHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.handleWindowEvent(Window.java:1266)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.notifyClose(Window.java:1174)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(WinApplication.java:218)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:511)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:107)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:583)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:474)
    at frontend.EditActionWindow.<init>(EditActionWindow.java:34)
    at MainController$2.handle(MainController.java:277)
    at MainController$2.handle(MainController.java:1)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My understanding is that an argument mismatch exception is thrown for the onHiding handler and the onHidden handler for the date pickers. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`onHidden`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#onHiddenProperty) and [`onHiding`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#onHidingProperty) properties are `EventHandler<Event>`, not `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`. Therefore the argument passed to the handler method is an instance of `Event`. When the `FXMLLoader` inspects the method you specify, it sees the parameter type is an `ActionEvent`, and consequently throws the exception.

Just change the parameter type for the `onHidden` and `onHiding` handler methods to `Event`:

```
@FXML
void currentDatePickerOnHidden(Event event) {

}

@FXML
void currentDatePickerOnHiding(Event event) {

}

@FXML
void eventualDatePickerOnHidden(Event event) {

}

@FXML
void eventualDatePickerOnHiding(Event event) {

}
```